# Get list of blocked requests in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to get a list of requests that are blocked by the browser (HTTP on HTTPS sites). I tried

```
page.on('requestfailed', request => {
        console.log(request.url());
        console.log('failed');
    });
```

but it did not provide the requests. The only requests I saw were those of URLs that do not exist anymore. The blocked (HTTP) request do also not trigger the request event.

```
page.on('request', request => { 
   console.log(request.url());
}
```

Is there another event I can listen to?

EDIT:

I can see that something failed when I use

```
page._client.on('Network.loadingFailed', async event => {
        const request = await page._networkManager._requestIdToRequest.get(event.requestId);
        console.log(event);
        console.log(request);
    });
```

but the request var is undefined. So I don't know which request failed.

Answer (score 5):

Found out how to solve this

```
page._client.on('Network.loadingFailed', async event => {
    if (requestToBySend[event.requestId] !== undefined) {
        let reason = '';
        if (event.blockedReason !== undefined) {
            reason = event.blockedReason;
        } else {
            reason = event.errorText;
        }
        console.log('blocked: ' + requestToBySend[event.requestId] + '; reason: ' + reason);
    }
});

page._client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', async event => {
    requestToBySend[event.requestId] = event.request.url;
});
```

The requestId is known on requestWillbeSent event. I just store those ids to look them up when I need them.

The Chrome events I use can be found here: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#event-loadingFailed